# Save and reproduce touch, mouse and keyboard input events

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qtquick2

Is there elegant way to save and reproduce later all the input events (or at least touch ones) since *Qt Quick 2* application's start until it closed or crashed/killed?

I can save all the input events of interest using the following approach (not full implementation):

```
class InputEventLogger
        : public QObject
{

    Q_OBJECT

public :

    explicit InputEventLogger(QObject * const parent = Q_NULLPTR)
        : QObject{parent}
    { ; }

protected :

    bool eventFilter(QObject * watched, QEvent * event) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
    {
        switch (event->type()) {
        case QEvent::KeyPress :
        case QEvent::KeyRelease : {
            qDebug() << event->type();
            const auto keyEvent = static_cast< QKeyEvent * >(event);
            qDebug() << keyEvent->key() << keyEvent->text();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::MouseButtonPress :
        case QEvent::MouseButtonRelease :
        case QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick :
        case QEvent::MouseMove : {
            qDebug() << event->type();
            const auto mouseEvent = static_cast< QMouseEvent * >(event);
            qDebug() << mouseEvent->pos();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::TouchBegin :
        case QEvent::TouchUpdate :
        case QEvent::TouchEnd :
        case QEvent::TouchCancel : {
            qDebug() << event->type();
            const auto touchEvent = static_cast< QTouchEvent * >(event);
            qDebug() << touchEvent->touchPoints();
            break;
        }
        case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseMove :
        case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMousePress :
        case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseRelease :
        case QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouseDoubleClick : {
            qDebug() << event->type();
            break;
        }
        default : {
            break;
        }
        }
        return QObject::eventFilter(watched, event);
    }

};

qApp->installEventFilter(new InputEventLogger{qApp});
```

`QGraphicsScene` accepts `QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouse*` events (translated from `QEvent::MouseButton*/MouseMove`). So, I need to translate corresponding events, before I pass them to `QApplication::sendEvent()`.

Along with events I want to save their timestamps to reproduce them in exact manner in greater extent possible.

How to reproduce user input as realistic as possible?

Comment: I do not understand your difficulties. If you capture a `QEvent::MouseButton*` event for a specific widget, why couldn't you send it out again to the same widget? I expect Qt will translate it again to `QEvent::GraphicsSceneMouse*` during replay. What is your problem with remembering timestamps?

Comment: @m7913d When I move one touch point there are also mouse events arrived.